# MikTeX 2.9 latest version Windows 10 - 64 bit

Tags: windows, miktex2.9

Please suggest where should I download the complete installation setup for `MikTeX 2.9` for `Windows10 (64 bit)`, I've tried but found `Basic-installer` only.

Please help...

Comment: https://miktex.org/download and then go to the tab "all downloads".

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Much thanks, now downloaded and installed....